# Hibernate INNER JOIN ManyToOne

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

e.g. Having two class

```
@Entity(name = "member")
public class M_Member{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "n")
    private String n;
}

@Entity(name = "task")
public class M_Task{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "n")
    private String n;

    @Column(name = "id_member")
    private int id_member;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="member")
    private M_Member member;
}
```

When running HQL:

```
FROM task t JOIN t.member WHERE t.id=1
```

Returns empty list.  Which in database

```
task
id, n, id_member
1, "A", 1
2, "B", 1
3, "C", 2

member
id, n
1, "MA"
2, "MB"
```

How to return the proper list containing the HQL suppose to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want **always** when fetching `M_Task`, its `M_Member` to be fetched, you can simply use `FetchType.EAGER` in your `@ManyToOne` annotation. So, you can just execute this query:

```
FROM M_TASK t
```

But if you don't want enable `FetchType.EAGER` by default, you can use `JOIN FETCH` in this way:

```
FROM M_TASK t JOIN FETCH t.member
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you map "M_task.id_member" if you have "M_task.member.id"?

Try this, e.g.:

```
@Entity(name = "member")
public class MMember{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "n")
    private String n;
}

@Entity(name = "task")
public class MTask{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "n")
    private String n;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_member")
    private M_Member member;
}
```

Run this HQL:

```
FROM MTask task JOIN FETCH task.member member WHERE member.id = 1
```